# Reduce chapter size in the cleanthesis template

Tags: templates, thesis, cleanthesis

In the cleanthesis, chapter titles take too much space, even short ones. For example,

> \chapter{The title of this chapter is not too long}

will be split into two lines. Is there any way to:

1. Increase the width of chapter title
2. Reduce the size of the chapter number (it is too big really!)
3. Expand a little the margin of the document (the margin is too large and the text content too narrow)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    \usepackage{cleanthesis}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{The title of this chapter is not too long}
    \end{document}
```

[image]